# Replace all `n*` by `n` instances of data that follows `*`

Tags: regex, replace, ultraedit

The Eclipse reservoir simulator takes ASCII data files as input. They have a way to compress saved data, so when inputting their saved data, they have to expand it like this:

```
4*0 4*1 0 3*1 5*0 1 0 2*1 10*.2
Expanded to
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2 .2
```

The times of repetition is any positive integer except 1, and the data could be any non-negative real number.

Given a string of compressed data, use regular expression to achieve expansion. What should I write in replace line? Would appreciate an example in UltraEdit; scripting / macros are accepted.

Original Regex:

```
   Find: (\d+)\*(\d)
Replace:
```

Comment: The syntax for the replacement parameter in a search-and-replace is not part of regular expression syntax, and is entirely dependent upon the tool being used.

Comment: @MarkReed I prefer a solution that could be performed in UltraEdit, either its builtin engine or its UNIX engine. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You'll need some kind of turing-complete machinery to do this -- maybe for example, macro scripting that ultraedit provides? To do the expansion you're asking for would require regex to be able to count. That's not something it can do by itself without some kind of embedded code.

Comment: Is it for single-digit only, or is it supposed to support multi-digit numbers? For example, is `10*9` a valid compression for `9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well, yes, multi-digits are supported. I forgot to say every float after that are also supported by eclipse. Like `110*.2` means 110 instances of `0.2`, separated by blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of replacement requires a general string expression on the replacement side, and as far as I know, UltraEdit doesn't supply that with just the "Find/Replace With" interface.  But you can write a script to do it:

```
UltraEdit.activeDocument.write( 
  UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection.replace(
    /(\d+)\*(\S+)/g,
    function(_, count, value) { 
      return new Array(count-0+1).join(value+' ').replace(/ $/,''); }
));
```

Comment: I'm new to macro/scripting in UltraEdit. Provided that UltraEdit could still match the search string in scripts, does that mean I have to use loops to write those data `n` times?

Comment: I added `var str = UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection;` before this script. I saved it as `re.js`, loaded it into the script list, selected a line `7*0 5*1 12*0 13*1 5*0 16*1 4*0` and it didn't replace. I'm also new to javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the scripting solution. UltraEdit has a Perl regex engine, isn't it able to run the perl code in your previous edits? I tried to put that into the find string but didn't work.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. that just lets you use Perl-compatible regexes for the match; the replacement doesn't give you a way to enter actual Perl code the way you can with `/e` in real Perl